# CORS and 'access control allow origin' error while using prefixfree.js and google fonts api

Tags: javascript, css, html, cors, google-font-api

I am getting errors related to CORS and ACAO. Working on html5 responsive website tutorial and just added the basic files which are needed to create the website as described in tut. Here are the screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution to problem # 1** First issue of CORS was resolved by using httml server locally as suggested by @destroy.

**Solution to problem #2** Just add prefetch after stylesheet to rel.

```
<link title="fonts" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/..." rel="stylesheet prefetch" type="text/css" />
```

*source : http://www.raymonschouwenaar.nl/google-webfont-issue-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load/*

Answer (score 2):

When you test your site, open it using the http protocol, don't open it in `file://`.

This means you must have a local http server to test.

Comment: You can use any http server. If you serve only static files, using node.js might not be the most convenient. Most people use Apache2. I use nginx. In both cases you just have to put your files in a subdirectory of the www root directory to have them served.

Comment: I started wamp server, added website files to www directory. CORS problem is not there anymore but google apis issue still.